# If exists update it, else insert - without primary or unique key (one query)

Tags: mysql

I have the following many-to-many table:

```
id   user_id comment_id like
1    1       1          true
2    1       2          false
3    2       1          true
4    2       2          true
```

I am trying to update a record if it exists (e.g. user_id = 1 AND comment_id = 1), otherwise create a new one. I cannot use unique key for user_id and comment_id columns because the same id can show up multiple times in this table. Is there any way of doing this with one query only?

Thanks,

Comment: Hint: `INSERT IGNORE ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: @tadman doesn't `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` require a pk or unique key?

Comment: Well yeah, but what you want and what's practical are sometimes two different things. You need a key (`UNIQUE` constraint) or this will not be performant at all. You can do it with a complicated mix of transactions and rollbacks, or just use the traditional approach.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the clarification! it worked grealty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your post, you should never have two rows for the same `user_id` and `comment_id` combination, making it an ideal candidate for a unique key:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT user_comment_unq UNIQUE (user_id, comment_id);
```

Once you have this constraint, you can use an `insert` statement with an `on duplicate key update` clause. E.g.:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`user_id`, `comment_id`, `like`)
VALUES (1, 1, TRUE)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `like` = TRUE
```